# Is there a way to get a happy home without streetpass or spotpass?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

My friend said one of her villagers just moved in and said she came from another town and she had a best friend. She said the next day the villagers best friend had a house in the happy home showcase. The villager that moved in and had the best friend was Uchi and was named Mira. Any way to have this happen to me?

Answer (score 1):

You can do all of the Happy Home tasks without streetpass/spotpass. Happy Home is about building out your house so that you get a high Happy Home score, and that is more about what items you place and where you place them. The only thing the Showcase affords you is an ability to view other peoples homes and potentially buy copies of items from their homes as available instead of waiting for the item to show up in the Nooklings shop.

Comment: Wait so if someone just joins my game and becomes my best friend or something their happy home house would be there?

Comment: Hmm... No, that's not quite how it works. Having someone visit your town or listing them as a best friend doesn't count as a streetpass. Streetpass happens when you are in physical proximity of the other player (within about 200 feet/70 meters) and the systems connect and share player info. If they have a home in the showcase, their home will streetpass to your showcase and vice versa,

Comment: Don't forget about the QR codes that can mod your save. That helps a lot too.